# How to consume a Web service in visual studio from only the wsdl

Tags: visual-studio, web-services

I have a new project whereas i need to consume a webservice from the following address: http://opensearch.addi.dk/1.1/
The service is a library service for querying books etc. When i feed my visual studio the wsdl (shown in bottom of page) i cannot consume it or Call it. Shouldnt this be this simple or am i missing something. I would hate to be forced to write All the soap XML myself and to parse the request.

Anyone know if im missing something?

**EDIT**
It seems VS cannot resolve this xsd

```
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="dcterms.xsd">
<xs:group name="elementsAndRefinementsGroup">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:group ref="elementsAndRefinementsGroup"/>
<xs:element ref="anyElements"/>
</xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
</xs:redefine>
```

because it has a self-reference within a group. This is legal according to the xsd specification, but VS doesnt seem to agree...

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "feed my visual studio the wsdl"?  Are you using it to add a Service Reference?  Adding a file containing the WSDL to your VS project?  Something else?

Also, it would probably help if you mentioned which version of Visual Studio you are using.

Comment: Using vs2010, just using the ADD service reference, cmi King advanced, Then ADD Web reference

Comment: Why are you using "Add Web Reference"?

Comment: Please see my answer to Michael Kennedy below

Comment: I get a circular reference when VS tries to resolve the xsd shown in my EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `wsdl.exe` and pass in the file and the final URL, namespace, etc. in the commandline.

Be sure to use a "Visual Studio Command Prompt", not the regular one.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it fails, with an error: "The binding "osSearchServiceSoapBinding" cannot be imported from the namespace "http://oss.dbc.dk/ns/opensearch_wsdl.
The action "search" cannot be imported. The Group "elementAndRefinementsGroup" from the targetNamespace="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" has an invalid definition: Circular reference.

Roughly translated from my danish error message

Comment: Possibly it's an advanced WCF binding rather than straight SOAP 1.1? You can try a similar command with SvcUtil.exe.