# Building a custom class from WSDL file in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamic, wsdl

I'm trying to find a way to read in a WSDL file (I will not have the source of the service) that requires a custom type as input.
I am currently trying to test with this file http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

So in this I am dynamically calling the ConversionRate method. I input two strings for the "ToCurrency" and "FromCurrency" fields needed and then I use String.Format and create a class named the same as the expected one "Currency" in this case and I've made the to/from currency as public strings in the class I create and set them to the two input strings I gave in the beginning. When I try to invoke the service this way I get an error like cannot convert type Currency to Currency.

I assume this is because the class I've created is not the same as the one implemented in the code for the service I'm calling.

My question is this, can I create a class of the appropriate type to successfully pass in and invoke the method using only the data I get from the WSDL file?

Comment: I am not merely trying to consume the service, I'm doing that already what I want is to create an object of whatever type the converter is expecting, and wrap my strings inside it so that I can get a response for it. I tried doing what Tung suggested and it seems to be on the right track however it gives me an error saying something like access to \wsdl File Path\CurrencyConverter.cs is denied.Any idea how I might get around this access denied problem, perhaps if it was done straight from code perhaps or another way to solve this if it can be solved. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Microsoft's wsdl.exe [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
wsdl.exe http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl
```

The tool can be found in your Microsoft SDK folder under program files. If all you want is to consume the web service, then Jen's suggestion is best imho.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the WSDL tool automatically generate proxy classes to work with the service: [How to consume a Web service in visual studio from only the wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156232/how-to-consume-a-web-service-in-visual-studio-from-only-the-wsdl)